# how to perform MultiLabelBinarizer with specific number of dimension?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, multilabel-classification

I wonder if there is a way to perform the MultiLabelBinarizer in sklearn with a specific dimension. For example we have the code as below:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

y = [[2, 3, 4], [2], [0, 1, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2]]

MultiLabelBinarizer().fit_transform(y)

We will get the dimension 5 as the existed numbers are 0,1..,4

array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0]])
```

My question is that How can we get the specific number of dimensions for this array for example dimension 6 so the answer should provide:

```
array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Is there a way to do this in sklearn or other methods or module in python that can handle this kind of desired result easily or we can just create this kind of array by our own algorithm?

Any ideas for this will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MultiLabelBinarizer` accepts a parameter `classes` where you can indicate the ordering of the classes to be found. Providing a class that is not in the original array will add an extra dimension of `0` entries:

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer


y = [[2, 3, 4], [2], [0, 1, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2]]

MultiLabelBinarizer(classes=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).fit_transform(y)

# output
>>>[[0 0 1 1 1 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [1 1 0 1 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1 1 0]
 [1 1 1 0 0 0]]
```

Note that since the parameter is actually meant to indicate the ordering of the classes, the sequence you provide is important. Further, when providing too few classes the unknown classes will be ignored and not appear in the transformed array.